# How to identify the objects and its usages in a solution/project?

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a set of class files (nearly 1500 files). I have the task of identifying the class's usages in the project/solution. I can navigate by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for one file, but I cannot do it for all.

Do we have any automated/semi-automated way of doing this?

Note that I am using ReSharper (2016.3.2) and VS 2015.

Comment: Can you right click on the class name and use `Find Usages`?

Comment: What kind of result do you want to achieve? As Mjwills suggested - you can use Find Usages - but it is work "file by file"

Comment: @mjwills . Yes i can try this. But I have to do it to all the 1500 files which is time consuming and need to create a report for the files which used the objects.

Comment: Wait, you want a list of all the usages of **all 1500 classes** ?

Comment: @AakashM You are correct .

Answer (score 0):

I see two variants.

1. Remove one class. You'll get tons of compilation errors, so it's enough just copy-paste them into the Excel file and filter by file name. The problem - as far as I remember there is a limitation of errors shown by VS, 200 or 400, maybe you will need to fix it in the Options.
2. Use Roslyn [DataFlow Analysis](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/learn-roslyn-now-part-8-data-flow-analysis/) , or [Control Flow Analysis](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/learn-roslyn-now-control-flow-analysis/), or just extract usages from [Semantic](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/learn-roslyn-now/) [Model](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/learn-roslyn-now-part-7-introducing-the-semantic-model/).

Comment: You are correct. But doing the same copy and pasting the usages for the 1500 files(objects) is the real challenge. I didn't try Roslyn. I will try and let u know.

Comment: @PITCHAIMUTHU if you have some experience in PowerShell you can try solve this problem in a scripting way: clone repo, delete one .cs file, run msBuild, parse logs, restore file, delete next file...